why is this triangle shader that I wrote splitting into four?
I wrote a triangle shader with an edge function and tried to use weight to color it in, but the colors split into 4 separate triangles each with their own smaller version of the shader for some reason. the drawing function is just two lines of code for color and position and should not be causing this error.

int edgeFunction(uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t x2, uint16_t y2, uint16_t x3, uint16_t y3){
        return (x2-x1)*(y3-y1)-(y2-y1)*(x3-x1);
}

std::vector<fragment> RGBtri(uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t x2, uint16_t y2, uint16_t x3, uint16_t y3){
        std::vector<fragment> tri; //fragment is a struct with xyrgba

        int minX = std::min(x1, std::min(x2,x3));
        int maxX = std::max(x1, std::max(x2,x3));
        int minY = std::min(y1, std::min(y2,y3));
        int maxY = std::max(y1, std::max(y2,y3));

        int p = edgeFunction(x1,y2,x2,y2,x3,y3);

        for(uint16_t y = minY;y<=maxY;y++){
                for(uint16_t x = minX;x<=maxX;x++){
                        int a = edgeFunction(x2,y2,x3,y3,x,y);
                        int b = edgeFunction(x3,y3,x1,y1,x,y);
                        int c = edgeFunction(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y);

                        if((a|b|c)>=0){
                                float d = ((float)a*255/(float)p);
                                float e = ((float)b*255/(float)p);
                                float f = ((float)c*255/(float)p);

                                uint8_t r = static_cast<uint8_t>(d);
                                uint8_t g = static_cast<uint8_t>(e);
                                uint8_t b = static_cast<uint8_t>(f);

                                 tri.push_back({x,y,r,g,b,255});
                        }
                }
         }
          return tri;
}

I got a lot of my information here
I tried a few variations but at most I got the rgb and cmy sections to swap.
my goal is to have red green and blue in the vertices of the main triangle, and not have the split

if((a|b|c)>=0) I'm 99% sure this is wrong. What do you mean by this line?

@MikeVine It's to check if all the variables are positive, and if they are all positive then the point is inside the triangle and gets pushed into the vector with a color

oh lol ok... I guess that would work but it certainly looks really weird. Why not just write it normally and let the compiler do the bit tricks :)

@MikeVine I had read that it would be faster that way, you're right about the compiler doing that stuff behind the scenes, both |'ing them together and doing checking each one separately made the same assembly instructions with O3 optimization on.

Compilers are written by people (for now) and people write optimization rules used by compilers based in what people recognize. You'll find a lot of the time that the compiler will optimize dead-stupid, easily recognized and interpreted code to be better than the sneaky stuff you're hand-optimized. For one thing it's often considering whole blocks of code rather than single lines. General rule of thumb is to write the code as stupid as possible, let the compiler take a crack at it, and only go weird after you've profiled the compiler's output and found it wanting.

Found the answer, point p is x1 y2 for the first point not x1 y1, abc should not be multiplied by 255, the result should be multiplied by 255 and then cast to uint8
std::vector<fragment> RGBtri(uint16_t x1, uint16_t y1, uint16_t x2, uint16_t y2, uint16_t x3, uint16_t y3){
        std::vector<fragment> tri;

        int minX = std::min(x1, std::min(x2,x3));
        int maxX = std::max(x1, std::max(x2,x3));
        int minY = std::min(y1, std::min(y2,y3));
        int maxY = std::max(y1, std::max(y2,y3));

        int p = edgeFunction(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);

        for(uint16_t y = minY;y<=maxY;y++){
                for(uint16_t x = minX;x<=maxX;x++){
                        int a = edgeFunction(x2,y2,x3,y3,x,y);
                        int b = edgeFunction(x3,y3,x1,y1,x,y);
                        int c = edgeFunction(x1,y1,x2,y2,x,y);

                        if(a>=0&&b>=0&&c>=0){
                                float w1 = ((float)a/(float)p);
                                float w2 = ((float)b/(float)p);
                                float w3 = ((float)c/(float)p);

                                uint8_t R = red.r*w1+green.r*w2+blue.r*w3;
                                uint8_t G = red.g*w1+green.g*w2+blue.g*w3;
                                uint8_t B = red.b*w1+green.b*w2+blue.b*w3;

                                tri.push_back({x,y,R,G,B,255});
                        }
                }
        }

        return tri;

}

